# Indexed/ordered queue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, queue

I have a multi-threaded application, each thread receives data from a serial/UART interface.

I want to print the data in order as they have arrived, however some data is longer, some is shorter and using `read_until` of `pyserial` leads to the order being mixed up (by few milliseconds/nanoseconds)

I would need something like a Queue but one that removes elements in sequential order to ensure I won't mix them up.

**Receiving thread**

1. Upon receiving a 1st byte of a packet I can "get a next number" (some thread-safe operation)
2. Then I can wait until all the data arrive
3. Then I can push the whole "packet" into the queue

**Consumer thread**  can only consume elements in the queue based on the sequential index, if eg. 1 and 2 were processed and there are 4 and 5 waiting already but I never got 3 I have to wait for it before moving on.

I do not want to reinvent the wheel - is this a construct I fail to name or does anybody know anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no such structure (similar to "ordered priority queue") in python standard library. And most likely you will have to implement something like a wrapper over `PriorityQueue` that keeps track priority of items, allows to extract only in an ordered manner, and buffers the rest.